# Array Like Object vs 2D arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

recently i heared about the term array like objects in javascript.
what is the difference between 2D array and array like objects.
Is there any advantages of Array like objects?

Comment: Did you try to Google "array like objects javascript"? Because this showed up as the second result for me: http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/.

Comment: @Catalyst yea . i searched. the question is 2D array and array like objects are equal? thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

*The question is 2D array and array like objects are equal?*

Short answer: No.

Array-like objects look like arrays. They have various numbered elements and a length property. But that’s where the similarity stops. Array-like objects do not have any of Array’s functions, and for-in loops don’t even work!

As @Catalyst mentioned in a previous answer, please have a look at [this link](http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/) for further information.

Hope it helps!